# how do I translate this aws cli patching command into something I can put into a python script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, patch

I am trying to use SSM run command to automate patching using Cloudwatch. This is the patching command

```
sudo aws ssm start-automation-execution --document-name "patching-document" --parameters
 '{"Parameter"],"InstanceId":["my instance"],"Backup":["false"],"Reboot":["RebootIfNeeded"]}' 
--region us-east-1
```

Will it be possible to put this command into a python script then execute it on aws cloudwatch for automated patching?

Answer (score 2):

To access the AWS Systems Manager API in python, can use [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html), the python SDK for AWS. For your specific use case there is the [`start_automation_execution`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.start_automation_execution)-command.

Your code would look similar to this:

```
import boto3
ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='us-east-1')
response = client.start_automation_execution(
    DocumentName='patching-document,
    Parameters={...},
    ...
)
```